# URLLoader at Actionscript

Tags: actionscript, urlloader

At the URLLoader reference there is the following example:

```
       private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
                var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target); 
       }
```

I cannot understand the `URLLoader(event.target)` syntax. It's not a call to the constructor, it's not a method invocation or a static method invocation. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a cast.  In this example they are simply casting the event.target, which was a URLLoader as such.

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten the actionscript syntax of casting (I was thinking that it's the same with Java)